# Access SERVLET from Javascript using $http

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, tomcat8

I'm having some difficulties resolve a strange situation.

I have the following AngularJS module:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp'); 
MyApp.factory('DB_Services', ['$http' , '$q' , function($http , $q) {
    var l_Result ;
    var DB_Services = function(p_URL_Root , p_Query) {
        var l_deferred = $q.defer();
        var l_params   = JSON.stringify(p_Query) ;
        var l_url      = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/MEKUWQDispatcher/DispatcherClass?";
        var l_params   = 'request=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(p_Query)) ;        
        var req = { url    : l_url, 
                    method :"GET", 
                    timeout:10000 , 
                    headers: { 
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json ; charset=UTF-8'
                    }, 
                    data:l_params
                  } ;
        $http(req ).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                         l_deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                         l_deferred.resolve(status);
                    });
                    return l_deferred.promise;
        return l_deferred.promise;
    } ;

    return DB_Services;

}]);
```

It sends a request to a JAVA-based SERVLET running on top of TOMCAT8.

The SERVLET includes the following piece of code:

```
   :
   :
   final String DB_URL="jdbc:sqlserver://RSHSQLTDBD\\SQLDBD:1434;DatabaseName=" + DB_Name + ";user=" + USER + ";password=" + PASS ;

    Connection          conn                       = null                              ;
    Statement           stmt                       = null                              ;
    CallableStatement   Call_stmt                  = null                              ;
    ResultSet           rs                                                             ; 
    boolean             ExecutionResult                                                ;
    String              Web_Request                = request.getParameter("request")   ;
    String              Web_Response               = null                              ;
    int                 Web_Result_Code            = 0                                 ;
    String              Web_Result_Description     = null                              ;

    // Register driver to DB...
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (Web_Request == null) {
    :
    :
```

So, if no request is received, it response with the results of a hardcoded **select** statement sent to the database, otherwise it invokes a Stored Procedure to which the request is sent.

The connection to the DB appears to work since, using the browser, invocation of the servlet with no data shows the result of the hardcoded select statement.

My problems are:

1. Regardless of what I send (through the parameter `p_Query`), the servlet does not see any request (i.e. in the JAVA statement `if (Web_Request == null)` the variable `Web_Request` is always `null`) and it returns the result of the hardcoded select statement,
2. If (within the JavaScript) I change the `GET` to `POST`, I get a 404 error code (not found, also shown in the logs of TOMCAT),
3. Though my development environment (Brackets) and TOMCAT are running in the same machine, I'm getting CORS error unless I run CHROME with Web Security disabled.

### Clarification

The SERVLET includes `doGet` and `doPost` functions (regarding point 2 above).

Comment: I have example using spring MVC.

Comment: @Grzesiek, don't understand what you mean... Are you trying to say something more that simply stating that you have an example?

Comment: We create open source web app where use spring framework (spring MVC, Spring jdbc), operations on database use stored procedure (DAO) dao use in service, service use in controler witch have REST. We have error propagation from the database to the Rest (error translation) etc .. We use angular2 (pack to war) And don't have problem with CORS.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't think I will switch platforms at this point. CORS should complain when you are trying to implement CROSS-DOMAIN retrieval from your application. In my case, both the Web and SERVLET servers are running on the same machine, and hence there is no CROSS DOMAIN condition. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Web and servlet run the same port?

Comment: Obviously not. As explained, the SERVLET is programmed to return a hard-coded select operation (from the database) in case it receives an empty request. This is currently what I get with both an empty and not empty requests (meaning, the servlet is reached in both cases). Additionally, if I add data to the request when using the browser I get an error that the web page cannot be found. I think the issue is with the service definition in TOMCAT... Will check it and post if this was the case.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know about servlet but simple controller in spring MVC for REST work me.

Comment: It's OK. You tried at least. Thanks.